# Eclipse 3.x Automatic opening compare merge editor given two text files

Tags: eclipse, compare, launch

does anybody know how to open programmatically (not manually) the compare merge editor simply passing two file names? Lot of search everywhere but haven't found anything.
Thanks for any help

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: This is not straightforward. You need to call `CompareUI.openCompareEditor` with a suitable `CompareEditorInput`. More in the [Eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fcompare.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a compare/merge editor I suggest [Winmerge](http://winmerge.org/) or [P4Merge](http://www.perforce.com/product/components/perforce-visual-merge-and-diff-tools), both are free and you can call them from command line.